# Count age within its range in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having trouble lately about counting the duplicate array ang make it object. Now, I'm trying to solve counting age with its range.
I have this code snippet to count duplicate age.

```
const age = [5, 5, 16, 5, 16];

const sumAge = {};
for (const datum of age) {
    let entry = sumAge[datum];
    if (entry) {
        ++entry.count;
    } else {
        sumAge[datum] = {age: datum, count: 1};
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(sumAge));
```

I have a result

```
{
   age:5,
   value: 3
},
{
   age:16,
   value: 2
}
```

Ivm trying to solve this expected result

```
{
   age:5-15,
   value: 3
},
{
   age:16-30,
   value: 2
}
```

Comment: So, what determines the age ranges? Just fixed `5-15` and `16-30`? What if 31 is in the dataset? or 2?

Comment: Expected 5 is the minimun and 30 is max

Comment: @Valkenswaard there's nothing in your example that defines the age ranges (5-15 and 16-30) though.

Comment: @phuzi I think that's the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of some definition of the age brackets, this is fairly straightforward. Use `find` to determine the right age bracket and use that as your key. Optionally use something like `Other` when the age is not in one of the ranges.

```js
const age = [5, 5, 16, 5, 16,99];
const ranges = {
   "5-15":{ min:5, max:15},
   "16-30":{ min:16, max:30},
}

const sumAge = {};
for (const datum of age) {
   var range = Object.keys(ranges).find(r => ranges[r].min<=datum && ranges[r].max>= datum) || "Other";
    let entry = sumAge[range];
    if (entry) {
        ++entry.count;
    } else {
        sumAge[range] = {age: range, count: 1};
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(sumAge));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it

```js
const age = [5, 5, 16, 5, 16];
// pre-define your age ranges - I'd always include one with Infinity
const ranges = {
    '0-4': {low: 0, hi:4, value:0},
    '5-15': {low: 5, hi:15, value:0},
    '16-30': {low: 16, hi:30, value:0},
    '30+': {low: 31, hi:Infinity, value:0}
};
const rangeArray = Object.values(ranges);
for (const datum of age) {
    rangeArray.find(range => range.low <= datum && datum <= range.hi).value++;
}
const sumAge = Object.entries(ranges).filter(([_, {value}]) => value).map(([age, {value}]) => ({age, value}));

//
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumAge, null, 4));
```